# Post Data via Url with Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, post, sinatra

I am developing an api-like app that allows other applications to send requests which trigger a series of actions in the api-like application. I need to find a way to send large parameters (embed code) via url. I'm using Sinatra.

My first attempt: (Doesn't work because embed code is not an acceptable url parameter)

```
get '/grab/:name/:bucket/:embed_code' do
  @video = Video.create(
    :name => params[:name],
    :bucket => params[:bucket],
    :embed_code => params[:embed_code],
    :created_at => Time.now
  )
  redirect "/video/#{@video.id}"
end
```

My second attempt: (`Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)` Error)

```
# (get '/video_form') points to (post '/video') and post_form was supposed to trigger it

get '/video_form' do
  erb :new_video
end

post '/video' do
  @video = Video.create(
    :name => params[:name],
    :bucket => params[:bucket],
    :embed_code => params[:embed_code],
    :created_at => Time.now
  )
  redirect "/video/#{@video.id}"
end

Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost:4567/video_form'),{'name'=>'example_2', 'bucket' => 'bucket_name', 'embed_code' => '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'})
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, and what you are having trouble with. Is your problem creating a Sinatra route that _receives_ and _handles a POST request, or is your problem writing Ruby code that _sends_ a POST request?

Comment: I need a way to pass parameters to the route so that I can store them in my database. The problem is that embed code cannot be passed via routes in Sinatra. I'm looking at json but I do not know how to accomplish this with json. (I understand why it is not possible to pass embed code via routes but I need to find some way to do this using json or some other method)

Comment: What do you mean that "the embed code cannot be passed via routes"? That makes no sense to me. Via GET or POST you pass string key/value pairs over HTTP. Sinatra routes (both GET and POST) can receive values. If you send it, it will be received.

Comment: So this (<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>) can be passed as a paramater? How would this request look? http://localhost:4567/grab/ex_name/ex_bucket/<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/http://www.youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Sinatra/Rails doesn't use (?=data) for parameters like Php and it's frameworks. Without that, how can the embed code be contained in the request?

Comment: See my answer, now that I sort of understand your confusion.

Comment: I recreated the first attempt and that's how the url came out when I submitted the request. (It resembles the GET request that you entered above) However, the application did not recognize that route, although it follows the pattern that I set with '/grab/:name/:bucket/:embed_code` This is why I thought that it could not be done

Comment: Write your Sinatra route to accept the parameter on the query string, not as a "path" portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper GET request might look like `http://localhost/getit?embed=%3Ciframe%20width%3D%22560%22%20height%3D%22315%22%20src%3D%22youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ%22%3B%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C/iframe%3E`. For more information, read up on [Encoding Query String Parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding). Quoting:

> Some characters cannot be part of a URL (for example, the space) and some other characters have a special meaning in a URL: for example, the character # can be used to further specify a subsection (or fragment) of a document; the character = is used to separate a name from a value. A query string may need to be converted to satisfy these constraints. This can be done using a schema known as URL encoding.
>
> In particular, encoding the query string uses the following rules:
>
> - Letters (`A-Z` and `a-z`), numbers (`0-9`) and the characters `.`,`-`,`~` and `_` are left as-is
> - SPACE is encoded as `+` or `%20`
> - All other characters are encoded as `%FF` hex representation with any non-ASCII characters first encoded as UTF-8 (or other specified encoding)

You can try this yourself via:

```html
<form method="get" action="/getit">
  <input type="hidden" name="embed" value='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ"; frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'>
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

Notice that with this you don't have to encode the value yourself; the web browser does that when it sends the form. Alternatively, you can make this GET request via JavaScript:

```js
var embed = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ"; frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
location.href = "http://localhost/getit?embed="+escape(embed);
```

A POST request doesn't show up on the query string, but is encoded by the browser. Take the same HTML as above and change the method, and watch Sinatra receive it.

To receive a complex parameter in Sinatra don't try to make it part of the path, receive it as a proper parameter on the query string:

```ruby
get "/getit" do
  p params['embed']
end
```

Comment: My GET request looks like this `http://localhost:4567/grab/ex_name/ex_bucket/%3Ciframe%20width=%22560%22%20height=%22315%22%20src=%22youtube.com/embed/http://www.youtube.com/embed/ncL1UlvjiMQ%22;%20frameborder=%220%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C/iframe%3E` This is what gives me the error.

Comment: So if I encode the embed code then the GET request will be successful?

Comment: That's an ugly GET request, where you're not passing any parameter but instead are trying to cram the value into the path. No, it will not be successful if you create a horrible URL that Sinatra's routes cannot properly match. See my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not understanding everything right away. I am confused with the examples that you give above because the other parameters are missing (name, bucket). Can those be passed in too? And you are just focusing on illustrating the point that the embed code needs to be encoded?

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple parameters in a query string. Try putting two inputs in a GET form and submitting it and look at what you see on the browser address bar.

Comment: I recommend you read the entire Wikipedia article on query strings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

Comment: Thanks, at this point I'm struggling because now I understand that the embed code needs to be encoded but I need to find a way for users to send a request without making them use forms or javascript. Thanks for the help, I learned a lot. I'm accepting your answer.